Mathematica's algorithm for computing $\gamma$
Please note that this question is not a duplicate of What is the fastest/most efficient algorithm for estimating Euler's Constant $\gamma$?
I was looking for algorithms for computing $\gamma$ (Euler's constant) and various representations of $\gamma$, and I noticed something strange:
On this page (https://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/EulerGamma/09/), look all the way down; you'll find this formula:
$$\gamma=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!^2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{x^k}{ik!^2}-\frac{\log x}{2}\right)$$
Allegedly, the above formula provides an algorithm for computing $\gamma$ to arbitrary precision. They say

The above formula is used for the numerical computation of Euler-Mascheroni constant in Mathematica. The algorithm which is based on this formula is the fastest known algorithm for computing this constant.

Now this was quite astounding for me when I first read it.
Sure, it approaches $\gamma$, but how does one use it for computing $\gamma$? If you take the above formula and choose some $x$, how can you bound the error between $\gamma$ and your approximation?
I tried squeezing the formula for some "alternating character" that would somehow give a sequence of lower bounds and a sequence of upper bounds, but I failed.

Apparently , this series converges very quickly so in practice we will have to run $k$ to only a moderate number to get a very precise result.

I also wonder how it can be proven that this strange sum (Is Ramanujan still alive?) actually converges to $\gamma$.

You may find this formula mentioned in the MathWorld article for the Euler-Mascheroni constant; it is Equation $(44)$.  According to the article, it is based on Equation $(38)$, and the cited references are:

Brent, R. P. and McMillan, E. M. "Some New Algorithms for High-Precision Computation of Euler's Constant." Math. Comput. 34, 305-312, 1980


Trott, M. The Mathematica GuideBook for Programming. New York: Springer-Verlag, 2004. http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/

I should also point out that in many cases, Mathematica leverages efficient sub-algorithms in its internal computations.  So for instance, if the algorithm for $\gamma$ requires a computation of harmonic numbers, rather than a specific implementation, it could simply call one that was programmed for standalone use.
Addendum.  I found this paper:
Paris, R. B.  An Asymptotic Expansion for the Error Term in the Brent-McMillan Algorithm for Euler’s Constant
which gives more details and an error bound.

I'm reading Brent's paper, page 307. Can you explain what does "The iteration (10) is terminated when, to the working precision, $U_k=U_{k-1}$ and $V_k=V_{k-1}$." mean in mathematical terms? (As clearly $U_k\ne U_{k-1}$ and $V_k\ne V_{k-1}$ in the strict sense). How do you bound the error between $U_k(n)$ and $U(n)$, etc.?

@Nomas2 I haven't read the paper as I don't have time to study it in detail presently, but the idea presumably is to stop computing additional steps in a recursion when the difference between the current step and the previous step falls below a certain threshold, much like how if you wanted to compute a series representation, say $$e = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$$ to some number of decimal digits of precision, say $10^{-6}$, you would stop once the denominator $k!$ grew large enough.

So the "working precision" here is a kind of algorithmically imposed error tolerance.  It could be a machine precision bound, so in the case of floating-point arithmetic, it might be around the order of $10^{-16}$; but because the algorithm is intended to be used to compute $\gamma$ to arbitrary precision, the "working precision" here is a function of the number of correct digits of $\gamma$ you want to get.
